# How to fetch redirected URL using python? (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION not working)

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

I'm working on crawling information from a website: http://www.fatwallet.com
There are many redirected URLs. For instance: http://www.fatwallet.com/ticket/store/A4C?s=storepage
is redirected to http://www.a4c.com/?siteID=.7WaaTN6umc-s1Ih0x_Q67n6r7gInoh6Ug

I would like to use PHP to find out the redirected URL.
I have used "`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)`". I know it will automatically redirect `5` times.

However, the problem is, the page i get is not the final page, instead it's a page in between.

`curl_exec` returns:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily   Server: Apache   Location:
>   www。fatwallet。com/interstitial/signin   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Encoding: gzip   Content-Length: 20   Content-Type: text/html 
>   Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 12:03:19 GMT   Connection: keep-alive
>   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A9E28337052B56ADAC8451854A276210; Path=/;
>   HttpOnly
>
> HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily   Server: Apache   Location:
>   www。fatwallet。com/interstitial/signin   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Encoding: gzip   Content-Length: 20   Content-Type: text/html 
>   Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 12:03:19 GMT   Connection: keep-alive
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK   Server: Apache   Cache-Control:
>   no-cache,no-store,max-age=0   Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT
>   X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1   Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Language: en   Content-Encoding: gzip   Content-Type:
>   text/html;charset=UTF-8   Content-Length: 16949   Date: Mon, 13 Apr
>   2015 12:03:20 GMT   Connection: keep-alive   Set-Cookie:
>   list_styles=grid; Expires=Sat, 01-May-2083 15:17:27 GMT; Path=/
>   Set-Cookie: non_mem=f86c0692-826f-40f2-9fa1-1e2f9a957af8; Expires=Sat,
>   01-May-2083 15:17:27 GMT; Path=/   ............

It seems that the third redirected code is "`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`", but it is not the final page. If you check http://www.fatwallet.com/ticket/store/A4C?s=storepage you will understand what I mean. Also, there is no way to find the final URL in the page returned.
So my question is, could it be able to make curl continue redirecting even if it receives `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`?

Is there another way to solve this(by using snoopy or python)?
Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that last redirect is done via JS, not the native HTTP answer. You just need more advanced crawler with function to execute JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Just see the source code of the first redirected page (view-source:https://www.fatwallet.com/interstitial/signin) and you will find the last one in some HTML elements, it seems that some JS code is reading those values and doing the last redirect